# In my jsp page I am using multi image carousel but I need to disable infinite looping of images

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

Here I am using following jquery

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 40000
});

$('.carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this)).addClass('rightest');
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

Please some one help me to stop looping.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you can catch slide.bs.carousel event and stop bubbling of that event (necessarily when you are at edge nodes of carousel). You can track in which carousel item you're in from event object:

```
$(document).on('slide.bs.carousel', function(event) {
  var relTarget = event.relatedTarget;
  if(/* Your tracking logic here */){
    event.preventDefault();
  }

});
```